# Finding the values of $n$ for which $\mathbb{F}_{5^{n}}$, the finite field with $5^{n}$ elements, contains a non-trivial $93$rd root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

For which values of $n$, does the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{5^{n}}$ with $5^{n}$ elements contain a non-trivial $93$rd root of unity?

I don't know how to find the value of $n$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In this answer, I assume that the adjective *non-trivial* in the OP's question modifies the entire noun phrase *93rd root of unity* and not just *root of unity* and thus "nontrivial 93rd root of unity" means an element of *multiplicative order* $93$ and excludes the elements of multiplicative orders $3$ and $31$ which also happen to be included in the $93$rd roots of unity.

$\mathbb F_{5^n}$ contains an element of multiplicative order $93$ if and only if $93$ is a divisor of $5^n-1$, that is, $5^n \equiv 1\bmod 93$. The brute force way of finding the smallest value of $n$ is to just *calculate* the values of $5^1$, $5^2$, $5^3$, $\ldots$ modulo $93$ until you find the answer. So we proceed as follows:
$$\begin{align*}
5^0 & \equiv 1 \bmod 93\\
5^1 &\equiv 5 \bmod 93\\
5^2 &\equiv 25 \bmod 93\\
5^3 = 125 &\equiv 32 \bmod 93\\
5^4 \equiv 5\times 32 =160 &\equiv 67 \bmod 93\\
5^5 \equiv 5\times 67 = 335 &\equiv 56 \bmod 93\\
5^6 \equiv 5\times 56 = 280 &\equiv 1 \bmod 93\\
\end{align*}$$
Thus, $\mathbb F_{5^6}$ is the smallest field of characteristic $5$
that contains an element of multiplicative order $93$. For the benefit of @suchandaadhikari, we continue the above calculation
$$\begin{align*}
5^7 \equiv 5\times 1 &\equiv 5 \bmod 93\\
5^8 \equiv 5\times 5 &\equiv 25 \bmod 93\\
5^9 \equiv 5\times 25 &\equiv 32 \bmod 93\\
5^{10} \equiv 5\times 32 =160 &\equiv 67 \bmod 93\\
5^{11} \equiv 5\times 67 = 335 &\equiv 56 \bmod 93\\
5^{12} \equiv 5\times 56 = 280 &\equiv 1 \bmod 93\\
\end{align*}$$
and then unforgivably (that is, without ever mentioning the principle of mathematical induction) jump to the conclusion that $5^n-1$ is divisible by $93$ if and only if $n$ is a multiple of $6$.

Those wishing to include $3$rd and $31$st roots of unity among the nontrivial $93$rd roots of unity can carry out similar calculations of discover that $n$ must be a multiple of $2$ for $\mathbb F_{5^n}$ to include a cube root of unity while $n$ must be a multiple of $3$ to include a $31$st root of unity. So, the conclusion would be that $n$ must be a multiple of $2$ **or** $3$ for $\mathbb F_{5^n}$ to include a non-trivial $93$rd root of unity. Note that **or** is used here in its *mathematical* meaning which allows for both conditions to hold simultaneously (which makes $n$ a multiple of $6$) instead of its meaning in *ordinary English* where "$A$ or $B$" means that  *either* $A$ holds *or* $B$ holds, but not both unless "or both" is appended to the phrase "$A$ or $B$" to explicitly allow the possibility that both $A$ and $B$ might hold.

Comment: Thanks! Now i can understand this properly.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that nobody knows how to do this in a way that is significantly better than brute-force enumeration.

Comment: thanks for the help on the question. but it is also true that 'n' could also be any other multiple of 6, like 12, 18 and so on... all of these have the similar property, right?

Comment: @Ram Yes, as I said at the very end of my answer "... $\mathbb F_{5^n}$ contains an element of multiplicative order $93$ if and only of $n$ is an integer multiple of $6$." This means that $12, 18 ,24, \ldots$, all multiples of $6$, also have the same property exactly as you say.

Comment: Why is "a non-trivial 93rd root of unity" an element of order 93? I'd say that any root of unity that is not 1 is non-trivial, in particular, elements of order 3 and 31 should also work.

Comment: @Phira I agree, but many non-mathematicians who use finite fields in their work (e.g. engineers studying coding theory) tend to use _non-trivial_ to mean _primitive_ and that is the way I interpreted the question. My answer very carefully avoided both words entirely and answered what I believe was intended: "For which values of $n$ does $\mathbb F_{5^n}$ contain an element of multiplicative order $93$?"

Comment: @Dilip sir,  doesn't the field  $F_{5^6}$ contain every root of  $x^{93}=1$ ?

Comment: @suchandaadhikari Yes, of course $\mathbb F_{5^6}$ contains all the roots of $x^{93}=1$ but not all the roots are elements of multiplicative order $93$. The question (or at least the way I interpret it -- see my response to Phira above) is asking what are the values of $n$ such that $\mathbb F_{5^6}$ contains elements of multiplicative order $93$, and the answer is $n$ must be a multiple of $6$. If the question were "What are the values of $n$ for which $\mathbb F_{5^n}$ contains _a_ root of $x^{93}=1$?" the answer would be "All positive integers $n$" and somewhat different if _non-trivial_

Comment: @suchandaadhikari ... _non-trivial_ means multiplicative orders $3$ and $31$ are acceptable.  $\mathbb F_{5^3}$ contains elements of multiplicative order $31$ (which are roots of $x^{93}=1$ as required) and so $n$ need only be a multiple of $3$, not of $6$ as is needed for elements of order $93$.

Comment: I didn't know that "nontrivial nth root of unity" is synonymous to "primitive nth root of unity" .I thought "nontrivial nth root of unity" means anything except 1.The word "nontrivial" means not trivial but when it comes before the phrase "nth root of unity " , it forces us to look only at "primitive nth root of unity ". So in this case n can't be 3k for infinitely many k though  $ F_{5^{3k}} $ contains 93rd root of unity other than 1.Thank you for explaining so nicely sir. ..with regards

Comment: One more thing , If 6| n then $ F_{5^n} $ contains the subfield  $ F_{5^6} $ and so $ F_{5^n} $ contains primitive 93rd roots of unity  but if $ F_{5^n} $ contains a primitive 93rd roots of unity then how did you show from 93 | $ 5^n-1 $ that 6 | n ?

Comment: @suchandaadhikari $93 | 5^6 - 1$, and if $\mathbb F_{5^n}$ has $\mathbb F_{5^6}$ as a subfield, then the _multiplicative group_ of $\mathbb F_{5^6}$ is a _subgroup_ of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_{5^n}$, and so $(5^6-1) | (5^n-1)$.  Now, there is a well-known result to the effect that $x^m-1$ is a divisor of $x^n-1$ if and only if $m$ is a divisor of $n$. So, $$(5^6-1) | (5^n-1) \implies 6 | n.$$

Comment: But  why does a field $ \mathbb{F}_{5^n} $ where $ 93|5^n-1$ contain the subfield  $ \mathbb{F}_{5^6} $?

Comment: Dilip sir, thank you so much for explaining everything so kindly, I am really grateful. .with regards

Answer (score 8):

I'll give you one direction - see if you can do the other on your own.

Suppose we have a non-trivial $93$rd root of unity $\zeta\in\mathbb{F}_{5^n}$. Then $\zeta$ would, of course, have to be non-zero. So $\zeta\in\mathbb{F}_{5^n}^\times$, and by definition we have that the order of $\zeta$ as an element of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{F}_{5^n}^\times$ is $93$. By Lagrange's theorem, this is only possible if $93\mid 5^n-1$. Note that $93\mid 5^n-1$ if and only if $3\mid 5^n-1$ and $31\mid 5^n-1$, because $93=3\cdot 31$ is the prime factorization of $93$.

When does that happen? Look at the following table:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
 n   & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ \hline
5^n & 1 & 5 & 25 & 125 & 625 & 3125 & 15625\\ \hline
\text{mod }3       & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
\text{mod }31      & 1 & 5 & 25 & 1 & 5 & 25 & 1
\end{array}$$
The period of $5^n$ modulo $3$ is $2$, and the period of $5^n$ modulo $31$ is $3$ (the proof that this period holds for all $n$ is straightforward). Thus, the $n$ for which $5^n\equiv 1\bmod 3$ and $5^n\equiv 1\bmod 31$ (i.e. the $n$ for which $3\mid 5^n-1$ and $31\mid 5^n-1$) are those $n$ such that $2\mid n$ and $3\mid n$, i.e. the $n$ which are multiples of $6$.

Ok, so we've established that, if there is a primitive $93$rd root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{5^n}$, then it must be the case that $6\mid n$.

Is the converse true? Try to work it out yourself.

Comment: Zev - this is serious. We both need to go to sleep.

Comment: Haha ***neverrrrr***

Comment: +1 Do observe that the third cyclotomic polynomial
$$\phi_3(x)=x^2+x+1$$
is quadratic, so even in characteristic zero you never need higher than a quadratic extension to include primitive cubic roots of unity!