# Non-trivial 93rd roots of unity in finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, cyclic-groups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding the values of $n$ for which $\mathbb{F}_{5^{n}}$, the finite field with $5^{n}$ elements, contains a non-trivial $93$rd root of unity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148641/finding-the-values-of-n-for-which-mathbbf-5n-the-finite-field-with)

For which of the following value of $n$, does the finite field $\Bbb F$, with $5^n$ elements contain a non trivial $93$-rd root of unity?

1. 92
2. 30
3. 15
4. 6

Comment: I totally forgot that this is a dup. Good job spotting that, guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The multiplicative group of a finite field $\Bbb F$ with $\mid \Bbb F\mid=q$ is cyclic and so, by the theory of cyclic groups, it contains a unique subgroup of order $d$ for each divisor $d$ of $q-1$. Thus, the question becomes: for which values of $n$  we have that $93$ divides $5^n-1$?

Now:

- $5^{92}\equiv67^{23}\equiv40\bmod93$,
- $5^{30}\equiv(5^6)^5\equiv1\bmod93$,
- $5^{15}\equiv56^3=32\not\equiv1\bmod93$,
- $5^6\equiv1\bmod93$.

So, of the $n$ listed, the answer is 6 and 30.

Comment: What's with the intermediate steps? Why those particular factorisations?