# Primitive root of unity in finite fields

Tags: finite-fields, roots-of-unity

To find a primitive $n$-th root of unity in a field $F_q$ of size $q$, one takes the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $q^m \equiv 1 \bmod n$ and finds a primitive $n$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$ by the formula $$\beta = \alpha^{\frac{q^m-1}{n}},$$ where $\alpha$ is a primitive element of $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$.

But what is the reasoning behind this formula?

Comment: It's just group theory: if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $N$, with generator $g$, and $d|N$, the power $g^{N/d}$ has order $d$ in $G$. For you, $G = F_{q^m}^\times$.

Comment: Read [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/148641/15941), its answers and the comments on the question and answers.

Comment: ok, thank you, I think i get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: in any group, $$\text{ord}(\alpha^k) = \frac{\text{ord}(\alpha)}{\text{gcd}(\text{ord}(\alpha), k)}.$$

Comment: Why not just: $\text{ord}(\alpha^k) = \frac{\text{ord}(\alpha)}{ k}$.

Comment: The expression on the right doesn't always make sense.  Let's see, mod 5 the number 2 has order 4, so is the order of $2^3 \bmod 5$ equal to $4/3$?

Comment: @KCd I know this is old, but in fact the expression on the right always makes sense, since the gcd of $\operatorname{ord}(\alpha)$ and $k$ will always divide $\operatorname{ord}(\alpha)$ by definition of gcd. In the example you gave, the gcd of $\operatorname{ord}(2) = 4$ and $3$ is not 3, but 1.

Comment: @JohnCavanaugh I was actually replying not to Unit, but to Isostorm, who commented just above me. I was pointing out to Isostorm that ${\rm ord}(\alpha)/k$ is not a valid order formula sometimes.